# Scraping from VBA - scraper already works on some data but not others

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I have used code from this website to pull data from property site Foxtons, the code is as follows

```
Sub foxtons()

Const READYSTATE_COMPLETE = 4

Dim j
Dim xcolElements
Dim Doc, ell, ie
Dim pn
j = 1
For pn = 1 To 10
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = False
ie.Navigate "http://www.foxtons.co.uk/search?current_page=" & pn & "&location_ids=288&search_form=map&search_type=SS&sold=1&submit_type=search"
Do
  DoEvents
Loop Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set Doc = ie.Document

Set xcolElements = Doc.getElementsByClassName("description")
'Here lies the problem. Description works perflectly, price doesn't

For Each ell In xcolElements
  Range("B" & j).Value = ell.FirstChild.Data
  j = j + 1
Next
Next pn
ie.Quit
Set el = Nothing
Set xcolElements = Nothing
Set Doc = Nothing
Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

The above code works and should pull in 600 property descriptions into column B. The problem arises when I switch "descriptions" to price. Here I receive an error message yet this is probably much more important for me

Comment: hope this finds you well. Would you still like to get in touch?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to retrieve the price elements:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Const READYSTATE_COMPLETE = 4

    Dim j As Integer

    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim Doc As IHTMLDocument
    Dim xcolElements As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim ell As IHTMLElement

    Dim pn As Integer

    j = 1
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    For pn = 1 To 10

        ie.Visible = True
        ie.Navigate "http://www.foxtons.co.uk/search?current_page=" & pn & "&location_ids=288&search_form=map&search_type=SS&sold=1&submit_type=search"
        Do
          DoEvents
        Loop Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

        Set Doc = ie.Document

        'Set xcolElements = Doc.getElementsByClassName("description")
        'Here lies the problem. Description works perflectly, price doesn't
        Set xcolElements = Doc.getElementsByClassName("price")



        For Each ell In xcolElements
          On Error GoTo Skip
          Range("B" & j).Value = ell.Children(0).Children(1).innerText
          j = j + 1
Skip:
        Next ell 

    On Error Goto 0

    Next pn

    ie.Quit
    Set el = Nothing
    Set xcolElements = Nothing
    Set Doc = Nothing
    Set ie = Nothing

End Sub
```

Good luck finding your new home :)

Comment: It works!!! Awesome mate, For some reason though I get an error message on the third iteration for Range("B" & j) etc etc. Any thoughts on that...... also, any chance i can schedule a skype call so you can walk me through what you did (I would pay of course) and also any change I can retain your help on one or two other projects?

Comment: @user3509663 glad it works for you! I was getting the same error, that's why I added the "On Error GoTo Skip" line as a quick workaround. Since then I'm not getting any more errors though. Can you please check that this line is present in your code? Feel free to contact me on Skype, I have added my username on my profile page.

Comment: Hi SilentSurfer, it seemed to work - am trying to contact you on Skype but having difficulty finding you!!

Comment: Hey I have added you , can you see ?

Comment: can't see you, sorry. Do you wanna put your skype name on your profile maybe?